# Adding a 0 to the Time in a VB Console Application

Tags: vb.net, time-format

I have created a console application in `VB.Net` that adds 2 times together and then displays the output of the final time. I've managed to get it working after much work but I have a problem:

Sometimes when I calculate the time and the end result is below '10 mins', it doesn't include the "0" in front of the minutes. I say this because all numbers under 10 mins on a clock are like 09, 08, 07, etc..

For example, I do 2:05 + 1:02 which the answer is meant to be 3:07 instead it comes out as 3:7. Another example would be I do 1:00 + 2:00 and the output is 3:0 when its meant to be 3:00.

Can anyone help me figure out this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the number using a custom format. Example:

```
Dim minuteString as String = minutes.ToString("00")
```

Comment: I dont understand? I already declared minutes as an Integer already? Where did string come from?